# App Engine and creating a private cache (java)

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm aware that App Engine has memcache build it. I'm using objectify, so all I have to do it add an annotation to use it.

I see one downside of the memcache solution and that is that Google have control. If they want to free up some memory on the server to supply another instance then they can empty my cache and I have to pay to refill it.

For this reason I'm wondering about creating my own cache as a hashmap of instances of objectify entities but I have two concerns that I'm struggling to find information on.

1. How can I monitor the memory usage of an instance to make sure I don't get too close to my 128mb limit?
2. I understand that objectify caches properties rather than whole entities in memcache. Is there a technical reason as to why I can't cache instances objectify entities?

Comment: creating my own cache as a hashmap of objectfify entities? Do you mean instance caching?

Comment: @Bharath Yes, caching instances of the objects. Sorry, that wasn't very clear.

Comment: App engine request will choose random instance. So this will add weightage to your instance. Are you ready for that?

Comment: @Bharath I understand that memcache will work across application instances, where as my cache will only work within the application instance it was created. But as I see it there's no harm or cost to using spare memory for a second cache. Memcache is still there to fall back on if required. Unless I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: Absolutely you got everything right. But it might have some problem if you need to remove some items from the map.

Comment: @Bharath Establishing when I need to remove items from the cache is my biggest concern. As I understand it, if I overfill my cache App Engine will complete the request and then kill that instance, which isn't the end of the world, but will create latency issues when it spins up a new instance.

Comment: I also thought Objectify cached properties separately, so I just checked: I looked in Memcache Viewer and see most of my top hits are Objectify entries, with what _look_ like Entity keys as the Memcache object keys.  If I try to lookup some of those keys, most return "key not in cache", but a couple of them returned objects.  The hex viewer suggests they are serialised entities (some are over 1K).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is for google app engine - python.

Yes. We are using cachepy currently in production with a decent success.

https://code.google.com/p/cachepy/

Note that this is an instance specific cache mechanism.

So you could use cachepy to cache it per-instance and also to memcache as a fallback before persiting to the datastore.

So when a cache miss happens on cachepy you can look up against memcache and when a cache miss happens on that as well you can fallback to to get it from the datastore.

For monitoring usage, you could do something like this ( although I am not sure if it will work as  I intend in gae )

on the set function on cachepy
https://code.google.com/p/cachepy/source/browse/cachepy.py#65

you could add a check to see the size of the cache using  `sys.getsizeof` and throw a `MemoryError` or something like that.

Comment: I'm using Java, but it's good to know there are solutions out there that already exist - so it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's also dedicated memcache, which might be an easier solution.

But to make sure you don't go over the memory limit you can probably use something like Ehcache and configure a limit.

As to your second question: as far as I know Objectify behaves like that to handle serialization and deserialization better when you deploy a new version and your classes might have slightly changed. When doing your own caching on your own instances you don't have that problem. However, eviction of old items from multiple instances is always tricky, so be careful with that.